# Ubuntu Terminal takes a while when performing commands using sudo

Tags: command-line, 18.04, sudo, gnome-terminal

my terminal takes a while to respond when I use commands with sudo. Any ideas as to what's up with that?

I saw a previous post saying it could be `/etc/nsswitch.conf` but didn't say what it could be inside that file. Just that it could be the problem. So here is my `/etc/nsswitch.conf` file:

```
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
# Example configuration of GNU Name Service Switch functionality.
# If you have the `glibc-doc-reference' and `info' packages installed, try:
# `info libc "Name Service Switch"' for information about this file.

passwd:         compat systemd
group:          compat systemd
shadow:         compat
gshadow:        files

hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns myhostname
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

Comment: Just a simple sudo apt-get update takes about a minute to bring up the password prompt for sudo.

Comment: Please edit your question instead of burying important information in comments - AskUbuntu is not intended for conversation.

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of https://serverfault.com/questions/38114/why-does-sudo-command-take-long-to-execute

Comment: Is this problem specific to GNOME Terminal?

Answer (score 0):

This could be the effect of changing the hostname during the installation.

Open the `hosts` file using:

```
sudo gedit /etc/hosts
```

After that, edit it according to the following:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4 <ADD_YOURS_HERE> 
::1 localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6 <ADD_YOURS_HERE>
```